# Good solution for individual list for each user in the intranet?

Tags: list, 2013, splistitem

I want to display items on webpart that the user have created and also can delete the items. Whats a good solution for this? I was thinkin of creating a regular list that contains all of the items and then filter them for each user but performance wise its pretty bad beacuse lets say there is 6000 items, I dont want to filter 10 items out of 6000. So my question is if there is any good solutions for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you go into the advanced settings for the list you can choose to ensure that users only see and edit their own items.  Getting the items from the list for each user should not be an issue as long as each user does not have 1,000s of items.

Comment: Which way of getting the items? With query?

Comment: A list view or CQWP will work great

Answer (score 0):

Or you can save the list as template, and give user the option to create list for themselves with a Dashboard showing items only for them!

If you don't want user to go into Admin and create new Item and list.. than you can customize that giving user a friendly Web Part and on backend create the List for user.. You will need a Configuration list to save each user's List Information!

Generalize development by creating multiple Web Parts

- Creation of User Specific list
- Dashboard to show items from his list

etc.

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented a solution that is to provision a list in each mysite so that the webpart that access to the list go to the list that is individually in the employee mysite.

The advantage is you only access very small list at a time so it is very quick.

**EDITED**

The solution consist on:

- Having a project MySite.Personalization project in visual studio pointing to MySite Host Web Application in the ServerConnection attribute with a ListDefinition called for example AppUser or whatever.
- Then you must have a Feature (mine is called FeatureListInstances) that contains the custom list.
- By the other hand I have another SharePoint project called MySite.Stapling also pointing to mysite host Web App with a module called Stapling that in the Elements.xml I have (among others) `<FeatureSiteTemplateAssociation Id="4008c0da-0127-4386-94e2-9ee8740d2420" TemplateName="SPSPERS#2" />`
- Deploy the solutions

With this situation whenever a mysite is created the AppUser list is created for that user.

Comment: How does the solution work and look like?